# What visa do I need to visit my uncle in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, family

I am planning to visit my uncle who is living in the UK for my next holiday.  Should I apply for a family visa or general visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check whether you need a visa at all. You haven't indicated your nationality, so presumably you have found that you need a visa.

According to [Family visitor visa eligibility](https://www.gov.uk/family-visit-visa/eligibility), an uncle is not one of the types of family members that would make you eligible for a family visa (it is generally only immediate family and direct ancestors or descendants). Therefore, you probably need to apply for a general visitor visa.